# Не создается C++ проект в Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

***Много способов испробовал чтобы исправить данную проблему,сколько раз переустанавливал visual studio не создавался проект,скачивал две версии visual studio 2019 и 2022 ни одна не работает,уже не знаю,что делать решил обратиться на данный форум за помощью***

***Код ошибки:***

The project could not be compiled.Would you like to open it in Visual Studio 2019?

```
Running D:/Gamedev/UE_4.27/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="D:/Gamedev/Projects/MyProject6/MyProject6.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Creating makefile for MyProject6Editor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject6Editor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Gamedev\Projects\MyProject6\MyProject6.uproject" "D:\Gamedev\Projects\MyProject6\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject6Editor\Develo pment\MyProject6Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_UHT.txt" -installed
LogInit: Display: Loading text-based GConfig....
Reflection code generated for MyProject6Editor in 4,3490191 seconds
@progress pop
Building MyProject6Editor...
Using Visual Studio 2019 14.29.30151 toolchain (D:\Gamedev\MS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Building 9 actions with 8 processes...
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0%
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 11%
[1/9] Default.rc2
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 22%
[2/9] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.cpp
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 33%
[3/9] MyProject6.init.gen.cpp
c1xx: error C3859: ?? 㤠???? ᮧ???? ????㠫???? ?????? ??? PCH.
c1xx: note: ???⥬? ????㫠 ??? 1455: ???? ?????窨 ᫨誮? ??? ??? ?????襭?? ?????樨.


c1xx: note: ???????⥫???? ᢥ?????: https://aka.ms/pch-help
c1xx: fatal error C1076: ??࠭?祭?? ???????????: ???⨣??? ?।?? ????७??? ????
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 44%
[4/9] MyProject6.cpp
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 56%
[5/9] MyProject6GameModeBase.cpp
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 67%
[6/9] MyProject6GameModeBase.gen.cpp
```

Надеюсь смогу решить проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Наблюдаются проблемы с кодировкой сообщений. Возможно это из-за того, что для VS установлена русская локализация.
2. Даже с этими крякозябрами суть сообщения об ошибке можно разобрать по ее коду, описание которого можно найти в документации. [error C3859](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3859?view=msvc-170) говорит о нехватке памяти на машине. Увеличивайте количество доступной памяти и/или сокращайте количество параллельно работающих процессов сборки.

Comment: а как можно увеличить количество памяти?

Comment: Ну если это десктоп, то пойти и купить плашек DRAM в магазине. На худой конец увеличить файл подкачки.

Comment: понял спасибо большое